# React native layouts ScrollView over View

Tags: css, react-native, layout

It's a two clickable button - 'Close' and 'Star'.
The 'Star' should be hidden by ScrollView. 
The problem is, when I make 'zIndex: -1' for a 'Star' button, it's becomes unclickable.

To make things clear, here is 10 sec video :
[youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKNtdLEcKT4&feature=youtu.be)

I also tried any other way to make it work, but can find a solution(

```js
 render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'tomato' }}>
        <Animated.ScrollView
          contentInset={{
            top: 450,
          }}
          contentOffset={{
            y: -HEADER_MAX_HEIGHT,
          }}
        >
          <ArticleText animation={{}} />
        </Animated.ScrollView>
        <View />
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.closeButton}>
          <Icon
            onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}
            name='close'
            containerStyle={{ padding: 5, backgroundColor: '#4f4f4f',                 borderRadius: 40 }}
            color='#ffff'
            size={30}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={[styles.starIcon]}
          onPress={() => console.log('pressed')}
        >
          <Icon
            name='star'
            color='#808080'
            size={25}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

.... styles {
  starIcon: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: -1,
    top: 180,
    right: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  closeButton: {
    zIndex: 1,
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 30,
    right: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    width: 40,
    height: 40,
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to put `zIndex:-1`  maybe try this:

```
closeButton: {zIndex:3}
ScroolView:{zIndex:2}
starIcon:{zIndex:1}
```

If this doesn't work try to put the `TouchableOpacity` inside a view with the position absolute styles, `TouchableOpacity`'s are weird with position absolute